# I don't understand how to make buttons in FLTK

Tags: c++, user-interface, button, compilation, fltk

```
#include "std_lib_facilities_4.h"
#include "Window.h"
#include "Graph.h"
#include "GUI.h"
#include <FL/Fl_Image.H>

using namespace Graph_lib;
using namespace std;

struct Lines_window:Graph_lib::Window{
    Lines_window(Point xy, int w, int h, const string& title);

    Button button_1;
    Button button_2;

    static void cb_change_color(Address, Address);
    static void cb_change_picture(Address, Address);
};

Lines_window::Lines_window(Point xy, int w, int h, const string& title) :

    Window(xy, w, h, title),
    button_1(Point(x_max()/2, y_max()/2), 200, 100, "Button 1", cb_change_color),
    button_2(Point(x_max()/3, y_max()/3), 200, 100, "Button 2", cb_change_picture)

    {
        attach(button_1);
        attach(button_2);
    }

void Lines_window::cb_change_color(Address, Address pw)
{

}

void Lines_window::cb_change_picture(Address, Address pw)
{

}


int main()
try {
    if(H112 != 201401L)error("Error: incorrect std_lib_facilities_4.h version ", H112);
    using namespace Graph_lib;

    Lines_window win(Point(100,100),600,400,"Buttons");
    return gui_main();

    return 0;
}
catch(exception& e) {
    cerr << "exception: " << e.what() << '\n';
    return 1;
}
catch (...) {
    cerr << "Some exception\n";
    return 2;
}
```

This is my button code. I am trying to make two buttons, one that changes color when you press it and another that puts an image on the button when you press it. I haven't made a callback yet because this won't compile. Errors are:

```
GUI.cpp:16:6: error: prototype for ‘void Graph_lib::Button::attach(Graph_lib::Window&, Fl_Color)’ does not match any in class ‘Graph_lib::Button’
 void Button::attach(Window& win, Fl_Color color)
      ^
In file included from GUI.cpp:10:0:
GUI.h:66:14: error: candidate is: virtual void Graph_lib::Button::attach(Graph_lib::Window&)
         void attach(Window&);
              ^
```

Do I need callbacks to compile? I am basing this code off of my professor's code [here](http://courses.cse.tamu.edu/jmichael/sp15/121/slide/code/graphics/sample-gui.cpp). I took everything out except for the buttons so I could make them. The GUI.cpp and GUI.h were given to us. What am I doing wrong?

GUI.cpp

```
//
// This is a GUI support code to the chapters 12-16 of the book
// "Programming -- Principles and Practice Using C++" by Bjarne Stroustrup
//

#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Button.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Output.H>
#include "GUI.h"

namespace Graph_lib {

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void Button::attach(Window& win, Fl_Color color)
{
    pw = new Fl_Button(loc.x, loc.y, width, height, label.c_str());
    pw->color(BLUE);
    pw->callback(reinterpret_cast<Fl_Callback*>(do_it), &win); // pass the window
    own = &win;
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int In_box::get_int()
{
    Fl_Input& pi = reference_to<Fl_Input>(pw);
    // return atoi(pi.value());
    const char* p = pi.value();
    if (!isdigit(p[0])) return -999999;
    return atoi(p);
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

string In_box::get_string()
{
    Fl_Input& pi = reference_to<Fl_Input>(pw);
    return string(pi.value());
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void In_box::attach(Window& win)
{
    pw = new Fl_Input(loc.x, loc.y, width, height, label.c_str());
    own = &win;
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void Out_box::put(const string& s)
{
    reference_to<Fl_Output>(pw).value(s.c_str());
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void Out_box::attach(Window& win)
{
    pw = new Fl_Output(loc.x, loc.y, width, height, label.c_str());
    own = &win;
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int Menu::attach(Button& b)
{
    b.width = width;
    b.height = height;

    switch(k) {
    case horizontal:
        b.loc = Point(loc.x+offset,loc.y);
        offset+=b.width;
        break;
    case vertical:
        b.loc = Point(loc.x,loc.y+offset);
        offset+=b.height;
        break;
    }
    selection.push_back(b); // b is NOT OWNED: pass by reference
    return int(selection.size()-1);
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int Menu::attach(Button* p)
{
    Button& b = *p;
    b.width = width;
    b.height = height;

    switch(k) {
    case horizontal:
        b.loc = Point(loc.x+offset,loc.y);
        offset+=b.width;
        break;
    case vertical:
        b.loc = Point(loc.x,loc.y+offset);
        offset+=b.height;
        break;
    }
    selection.push_back(&b); // b is OWNED: pass by pointer
    return int(selection.size()-1);
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

} // of namespace Graph_lib
```

GUI.h

```
//
// This is a GUI support code to the chapters 12-16 of the book
// "Programming -- Principles and Practice Using C++" by Bjarne Stroustrup
//

#ifndef GUI_GUARD
#define GUI_GUARD

#include "Window.h"
#include "Graph.h"

namespace Graph_lib {

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    typedef void* Address;    // Address is a synonym for void*
    typedef void(*Callback)(Address, Address);    // FLTK's required function type for all callbacks

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    template<class W> W& reference_to(Address pw)
    // treat an address as a reference to a W
    {
        return *static_cast<W*>(pw);
    }

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    class Widget {
    // Widget is a handle to an Fl_widget - it is *not* an Fl_widget
    // We try to keep our interface classes at arm's length from FLTK
    public:
        Widget(Point xy, int w, int h, const string& s, Callback cb)
            : loc(xy), width(w), height(h), label(s), do_it(cb)
        {}

        virtual void move(int dx,int dy) { hide(); pw->position(loc.x+=dx, loc.y+=dy); show(); }
        virtual void hide() { pw->hide(); }
        virtual void show() { pw->show(); }
        virtual void attach(Window&) = 0;

        Point loc;
        int width;
        int height;
        string label;
        Callback do_it;

        virtual ~Widget() { }

    protected:
        Window* own;    // every Widget belongs to a Window
        Fl_Widget* pw;  // connection to the FLTK Widget
    private:
        Widget& operator=(const Widget&); // don't copy Widgets
        Widget(const Widget&);
    };

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    struct Button : Widget {
        Button(Point xy, int w, int h, const string& label, Callback cb)
            : Widget(xy,w,h,label,cb)
        {}

        void attach(Window&);
    };

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    struct In_box : Widget {
        In_box(Point xy, int w, int h, const string& s)
            :Widget(xy,w,h,s,0) { }
        int get_int();
        string get_string();

        void attach(Window& win);
    };

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    struct Out_box : Widget {
        Out_box(Point xy, int w, int h, const string& s)
            :Widget(xy,w,h,s,0) { }
        void put(int);
        void put(const string&);

        void attach(Window& win);
    };

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    struct Menu : Widget {
        enum Kind { horizontal, vertical };
        Menu(Point xy, int w, int h, Kind kk, const string& label)
            : Widget(xy,w,h,label,0), k(kk), offset(0)
        {}

        Vector_ref<Button> selection;
        Kind k;
        int offset;
        int attach(Button& b);      // Menu does not delete &b
        int attach(Button* p);      // Menu deletes p

        void show()                 // show all buttons
        {
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i<selection.size(); ++i)
                selection[i].show();
        }
        void hide()                 // hide all buttons
        {
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i<selection.size(); ++i) 
                selection[i].hide(); 
        }
        void move(int dx, int dy)   // move all buttons
        {
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i<selection.size(); ++i) 
                selection[i].move(dx,dy);
        }

        void attach(Window& win)    // attach all buttons
        {
            for (int i=0; i<selection.size(); ++i) win.attach(selection[i]);
            own = &win;
        }

    };

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

} // of namespace Graph_lib

#endif // GUI_GUARD
```

Comment: The code you posted is the GUI.cpp? If not, please include the GUI.cpp relevant bit in your question. It seems there is an ambiguous method call in the GUI.cpp, on line 16

Comment: No this is my "main" CPP file.

Comment: Well, could you post it?

Comment: Added GUI.h and GUI.cpp

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It wouldn't compile because I added an argument to be passed to button (the Fl_Color). I will have to figure out a way to pass a value to the button to change the color.